# C++ Change private member of a class through only one other specific class?

Tags: c++, class, scope

How do I change the int 'a' inside class A but restrict the function that changes the int to ONLY class B? I do not even want A to be able to change it.

I have tried to create a friend function, but I get an error I included in the comments of the code. I then tried to just forward declare the function as a friend function in private and then actually creating the function in public, but the C class can access the public function. This despite me writing (in the private section) that the function is a friend function. Can I 'friend' a private value? I am unsure what to do here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    // forward declaration
    class B;
    class C;

    class A {
        private:
            int a; // private member I want to edit, but only via class B.
            int a2; // I would like to NOT be able to access this in class B. I only want to access and modify int a from class B, no other variable. If possible.

            // invalid use of non-static data member 'a'
            friend void test(int new_value) {
                a = 5;
            }

            friend B;
        public:
    };

    class B {
        private:
            int b;
        public:
            change_a_value(A a_class, int new_int) {
                a_class.test(new_int); // I want this to be possible.
            }
    };

    class C {
    private:
        int c;
    
    public:
        change_a_value(A a_class, int new_int) {
            a_class.test(new_int); // I want this to be impossible
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK in C++ you cannot restrict class A from the access to its private members. If you want the class B to be able to access class A private fields, just write `friend class B;` in the body of class A;

Comment: @pptaszni But you can at least restrict the public API of `A` from doing it.

Comment: @sweenish yeah I guess not creating a function inside class A prevents it from accessing and editing its own private members. But do I just "friend class B;" and then edit the private member from B?

Comment: This certainly can be done, but your question may need to describe _the problem you're trying to solve_ to ensure that this isn't an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Making `A` the owner of a variable it can not change, while `B` is the changer of a variable it does not own signifies that you have already chosen a very unusual design.

Comment: The calls and the definition of `a_class.test(new_int)` are not valid since `test()` is a `friend` of `A`, not a member function - so trying to make it succeed in one context but not another is a moot point.   In any event, the trust/friendship model in C++ is all or nothing - either a declared `friend` is trusted with access to all `private` members, or it is not declared a `friend`.    This strikes me as an XY problem.

Comment: Note that `a_class.test(new_int);` would be changing the value in a copy of `A` and that copy goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Add "void" before prototypes of change_a_value, and change the

```
friend B
```

to

```
friend class B
```

and suppress friend in

```
friend void test(int new_value) {
```

complete corrected program :

```
int main() {
  // forward declaration
  class B;
  class C;
  class A {
  private:
    int a; // private member I want to edit, but only via class B.
    int a2; // I would like to NOT be able to access this in class B. I only want to access and modify int a from class B, no other variable. If possible.
    void test(int new_value) {
      a = new_value;
    }
    friend class B;
  public:
  };
  class B {
  private:
    int b;
  public:
    void change_a_value(A a_class, int new_int) {
      a_class.test(new_int); // I want this to be possible.
    }
  };
  class C {
  private:
    int c;
  public:
    void change_a_value(A a_class, int new_int) {
      a_class.test(new_int); // I want this to be impossible
    }
  };
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation results are what was expected :

```
TestCpp2.cpp:9:14: error: ‘void main()::A::test(int)’ is private
     void test(int new_value) {
          ^
TestCpp2.cpp:28:31: error: within this context
       a_class.test(new_int); // I want this to be impossible
                           ^
Makefile:510: recipe for target 'TestCpp2.o' failed
make: *** [TestCpp2.o] Error 1
```

Comment: If my answer seems ok for you, can you accept it ? Thanks